# Prevent MatDialog From Closing When Clicked Outside with pending changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, dialog

I want to prevent close on outside when there are pending changes.
I something like this, but with no result.

```
this.dialogRef.beforeClosed().subscribe(() => {
  this.dialogRef.close(false);
  //some code logic
  //...
});
```

The `disableClose` on MatDialog have to stay `false`

Comment: `the disableClose on MatDialog have to stay true`? Do you mean `false`?

Comment: yeah, sorry, i'll change the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, while opening dialog, you can pass 'disableClose' as true, and later manually close dialog on backdrop click or escape click if there are no pending changes.

```
this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, { disableClose: true });

dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe( () => {
   if(!pendingChanges) dialogRef.close();
   // else do nothing
});
```

Comment: This is a good technique. I've just tried and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the case, you can initially set `disableClose` as `false`, so that user can close it if there is no pending changes, depending on what that pending change is, if it is an async call for example, you can set the `disableClose` as `true`.

You can also then inject the `MatDialogRef` into the component itself and manually toggle `disableClose` per your requirements, so something like this:

```
constructor(private matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<WhateverYourDialogIsCalled>) {}
```

then in a async call it could be:

```
onSubmit() {
  this.matDialogRef.disableClose = true;
  this.myService.doSomething().subscribe(_ => {
    this.matDialogRef.disableClose = false;
  });
}
```